# Is it possible to open your app with a non custom url?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, url, url-scheme

I followed a tutorial to open my app with a custom name myApp://. I will post some code to give everyone a better idea. But I am wondering if I can open an App with a url like so https://www.google.com/. I cant imagine this being possible due to the fact this can interfere with someone trying to get on google.

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
 {
if (!url) {  return NO; }

NSString *URLString = [url relativeString];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:URLString forKey:@"url"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
return YES;
```

Comment: See [x-callback-url](http://x-callback-url.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a full URL, it's only the scheme that specifies what the app handles. And no, you can't reuse URL schemes that are defined by another app.

Comment: So just to make sure, I can't have a url website when open to open my iOS App. I can only have the custom url or scheme that does it.

Comment: You can have a website of your own which redirects to your true custom URL scheme. Obviously the redirect will only work if opened on a device.

Answer (score 0):

**you are right in your assumption. you can't 'override' urls**... only one app can register a url scheme.

What you can do is have a http:// URL you control redirect the user to your app. But then you still need to control the website specified by the original url; so that isn't really the same as 'overriding' specific urls

(Facebook and the App Store and others do this)

---

so in short: sorry, you can't :/